# Game bot error (python chrome dinousor game error)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I followed a tut [Click me!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Jwd69MRYwg) and i get un-expected results: my code

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps
import pyautogui
import time
from numpy import *

class Cordinates():
   replayBtn = (960,355)
   dinosaur = (784,375)
   #770x360, 770x365

def restartGame():
    pyautogui.click(Cordinates.replayBtn)
def pressSpace():
    pyautogui.keyDown('space')
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print("Jump")
    pyautogui.keyUp('space')
def imageGrab():
    box = (Cordinates.dinosaur[0]+435, Cordinates.dinosaur[1]+25, 
    Cordinates.dinosaur[1]+335, 10)
    image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    grayImage = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    a = array(grayImage.getcolors())
    return a.sum()
def main():
    restartGame()
    while True:
       if imageGrab()!=1447:
            #pressSpace()
            print(imageGrab)
            time.sleep(0.1)
time.sleep(2)           
main()
```

and the print i added for debug gives me

```
<function imageGrab at 0x079CBD68>
```

What can i fix to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
if imageGrab()!=1447:
    #pressSpace()
    print(imageGrab)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

you `print(imageGrab)` like variable but you need to print like method

```
print(imageGrab())
```

you printed out a function, not a result of a function

Comment: Now it ust gets 0.0 @zimdero